# Running Oracle apex application with weblogic

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, weblogic, oracle-apex-5.1

I have developed an application with Oracle Apex 5.1 ( Database 11g). Now I have to make this application working with tables of another database (database 10g and web application 10g ) on another server. Is there and solution? Like working with weblogic or ...

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, that won't be easy.

Apex 5.1 requires Oracle database 11.2.0.4 or later (see [requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/Oracle-AE-installation-requirements.htm#GUID-ED8FE111-A861-4A54-938B-CB3664D49C68) ) (while your target database is 10g), so you can't even install it there so that you could export Apex application from your current database and import it into the 10g.

On the other hand, if you "Edit application properties", you can set the "Compatibility mode" to a lower version (such as 4.2, which can be installed on 10.2.0.4) and *hope* it'll work.

Also, note that - if you used some 11g functionalities that don't exist in 10g version - the application itself might need some adjustments.

Apart from Apex itself, you'd have to *migrate* the database schema to a new server because the application needs all those tables, stored procedures, etc. That process might get difficult if there are grants acquired from another users (that also don't exist in a new database).

In order to run Apex, you need

- Apex listener, or
- Embedded PL/SQL gateway, or
- HTTP Server and mod_plsql

There's nothing about a WebLogic server you mentioned. Basically, I think that this shouldn't worry you. Even if you install Apex by using its default settings, it *should* work. There's the "About choosing a web listener" chapter in every Apex installation guide, so - have a look and pick one that suits you most.

I can't tell it from my own experience as I've never downgraded an Apex application; someone more experienced might be able to assist better.

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot, Another question is this: Is there any solution for connecting Oracle Form and Report Developer 10g to Database 11g correctly??

Comment: Yes; that's what I have (Developer Suite 10g, database 11g) - works OK.